# What is it called when manipulating the body, such as with a smile, triggers emotion?

Tags: emotion, terminology, physiology, emotional-expression

Normally we smile as a consequence of being happy, but psychologists have, over the years investigated [the idea that smiling itself can cause happiness](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/04/190412094728.htm).

So, we have the concept of a physical act triggering an emotion in the reverse (or inverse) of what we would expect: the emotion triggering a physical behavior.

What is the psychological term for using a smile to trigger happiness?

Answer (score 1):

The specific example is called the [facial feedback hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_feedback_hypothesis):

> ... the conjectures ... that one's facial expression directly affects
> their emotional experience. ... While James included the influence of
> all bodily changes on the creation of an emotion ... modern research
> mainly focuses on the effects of facial muscular activity.

This is a component of the [James–Lange theory of emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Lange_theory):

> Instead of feeling an emotion and subsequent physiological (bodily)
> response, the theory proposes that the physiological change is
> primary, and emotion is then experienced when the brain reacts to the
> information received via the body's nervous system.

And also [self-perception theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-perception_theory):

> ... asserts that people develop their attitudes ... by observing their
> own behavior and concluding what attitudes must have caused it. The
> theory is counterintuitive in nature, as the conventional wisdom is
> that attitudes determine behaviors.